# Do badges give additional privileges or unlock features?

Tags: discussion, badges, privileges, incentive

So far as I can tell, badges exist to create incentive for good behavior, but they don't actually confer any additional privileges to the user, or unlock any features. Are there any badges that *do* unlock additional privileges or features?

Comment: Features yes, privileges no.

Comment: @Mat elaborate?

Comment: Manishearth pointed out a feature that gets enabled when you get a given badge - so yes, badges can unlock (at least one) feature (not aware of any others). But privileges are linked to reputation (and tag scores for synonyms and wiki stuff), not badges.

Comment: @Mat I've changed the question slightly to include features, since that's what I was curious about in the first place, and that's how the only answer seemed to intemperate the question.

Comment: It's clearer this way indeed. (No idea why someone would downvote this question... meta is a _strange_ place.)

Comment: @Mat: Lots of reasons. For example, there are no freehand circles.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yep. The Getting the Strunk and White badge lets you track your reviews in a comprehensive manner (as well as unlocking more badges). Observe:

[image]

<sub>Terms and conditions apply</sub>

Comment: Hmm, is that the only one?

Comment: @Shep: The only one I know of.