# Limited answer suggested edits based on reputation

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, new-users

I just had [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/835828) suggested edit come up in the queue and after it was rejected, I was curious about any comments or other answers and I noticed that the same editor has successfully edited this question once before and had a 2nd suggested edit rejected before this current rejection.

I have noticed that it is not uncommon for very new users to try to radically edit an answer as was done here (you can see how much was added from the suggested edit linked above and the edit history of [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1277196/revisions)).  For this specific case, I am not well versed enough to judge the actual content, but judging by the length of edits, it appears as if the editor put a lot of effort into the change and really did have good intentions, however, the changes probably should have been added as a new answer and not an edit.

I know we want to try to keep editing open and that is why we have suggested edits for users under 2K rep, but is it worth considering some sort of limit on the suggested editing capabilities of new users?  I realize that this is not a widespread problem, but at least from an answer-edit perspective, maybe there could be some limits.

I have a couple of thoughts in mind

1. Block answer editing/suggested editing for any user under 50 rep.  I picked a low number to try to keep it open, but 50 rep should be enough to get a rough idea when editing vs adding a new answer,
2. Try to examine the **length** of the edit and if it meets a specific threshold, maybe have a click through message box for low rep users that suggest they make their additions a new answer instead.

Bear in mind, I am specifically targeting answers and not all edits.  Generally speaking, editing answers has more impact on the quality of the information than editing a question.

Comment: it would be even better to have allowed limit of edit suggestions based on "edit weight" (feature proposed [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129853/165773))

Comment: The suggested edits are reviewed, and if a significant number of them are rejected, the user will lose the privilege for some time.

Comment: @BoPersson absolutely, but if original answer was changed so significantly (and accepted - which I know is another problem itself) then that won't come into play

Comment: @BoPersson also, having never had a suggested edit ban myself, I do not know what kind of message is provided, but unless real feedback as to why, I can see the editor continuing after the ban is lifted.  If we make is a privilege or a click through message, then the editor will at least be presented with real information as to what the answer-edit privilege is about.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I've been edit banned a bit more than a year ago. Message was pretty clear that the reason is too many rejected edits (6 in one day in my case IIRC)

Comment: @gnat I figured it was something like that, but my suggestions was partially an effort to try to educate as to why he/she had so many edit rejections if they were because of this situation.

Comment: @psubsee2003 well recalling that in my case ban was 2 (two!) weeks, I think this gives sufficient time to anyone *really* interested in improving learn _edi-quette_ (editing etiquette) themselves :)