Give the edit posts privilege to users with a history of good suggested edits
Currently, the only way to unilaterally edit posts is to have 2,000 rep (1,000 on beta sites).
Many users, for one reason or another, have experience editing but don't post very often, and hence take a very long time to reach 2,000 rep. (If they just edit, it could take 1,000 edits.) Having users with a long, established track record of good edits continue to go through queues takes users' time and potentially means that other edits will take longer to get reviewed.
I propose that any user with 50 accepted suggested edits and 95% accept rate (I'd be fine with changing the exact numbers a bit) be granted the edit privilege. This would include access to the edit review queue. I'd argue that having such a strong editing track record is probably a better indicator of whether or not their edits need review than their ability to ask and answer.
Could this be implemented?

Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/387365

This is already requested: Giving edit privilege based on number of trustworthy edits and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129839/377214.

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog While similar my proposals is different in some significnat ways, namely I'm suggested they be completely exempt from the queue, not just given high-priority.

That's exactly what both of those proposals suggest, no?

@Anerdw The body of the first merely suggests giving such edits higher priority, but the second says to exempt them. Unfortunately, the system doesn't allow changing the proposed duplicate target after voting; the best I could do was edit the automatic comment after voting.

Not a duplicate, but this is relevant: For edit-suggestors with a streak of N approvals, only require one approval for their next suggested edit

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog the second one suggests also just higher prioriity

No, it doesn't - it says One solution would be to allow bypassing of the queue for "established editors"
